# AWS lambda running the previous event's queue leftover functions

Tags: aws-lambda, event-queue

I am using AWS lambda for my application to get multiple records from dynamo using promises. Initially I set my context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true, so the handler will wait until the promises are resolved. Once the promises are resolved I am setting context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false and then calling callback(null);

If I don't set the callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false after the promises are resolved, the function is timing out even after I call callback(null)(some libraries functions might be still in the event queue).

So, the problem is if same the runtime is used again for next-time, the previously left over functions in the event queue are getting resumed, rather than starting all over again. Is there a way around this or even empty the previous event queue?

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;

allPromises = getDatafromDynamo();
allPromises.then(results => {
  console.log('Results are', JSON.stringify(results));
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  callback(null, 'DONE');
  return;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred", err);
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  callback(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question by making sure there is no global state maintained anywhere. Lambda uses the running process for next requests.